How to connect to a bluetooth device already connected to a smartphone
I have a Bluetooth headset (Soundcore Q30), and when it is connected to my computer, I can still connect to it via my Android smartphone and play sound on it.
However, if I want to do the opposite and connect my computer to the headset when it is already connect to my phone (even if not playing sound), bluez fails with the error:
SET_CONFIGURATION request rejected: Stream End Point in Use (19)
The error makes sense, but I am suprised my computer cannot do what my phone can. Is there a way to bypass that?
I am on Ubuntu 20.04 with Linux 5.15 and Bluez 5.53.

What you're looking for or the feature is Bluetooth multipoint pairing.
Your Android phone uses an advanced Bluetooth feature like multipoint support or SCO handoff, which allows it to override active connections.
The majority of headsets today feature multipoint technology and are compatible with a wide range of devices.
Bluetooth multipoint is often vendor-specific, so full functionality on Linux may still be limited.

Advanced Multipoint: Taking Single Multipoint a Step Further
"Advanced Multipoint" is almost identical to Single Multipoint. Let’s explore this small difference in detail: the primary function of "Advanced Multipoint" remains the same—two devices can connect to one headset, allowing you to handle two incoming calls.
However, unlike Single Multipoint, the first call isn’t disconnected when you accept the second incoming call. With "Advanced Multipoint," the first call is placed on hold, allowing you to return to it once you’ve finished the second call. You can even switch between the two calls, putting one on hold as needed.
Returning to the earlier example: with "Advanced Multipoint," you can quickly dismiss the sales representative on the line and, with a single button press, return to your conversation with a friend.
For this reason, "Advanced Multipoint" is now considered the standard for most headsets.

Try upgrading BlueZ if possible.
Here are some additional sources:

Is there a way to create a multiple connections BLE device in BlueZ?
Multiple BLE Connections using Linux and Bluez 5.0
Unable to connect multiple BLE devices
Bluez multiple audio sources
Bluetooth Management About BlueZ
Bluez doesn't work well with Multipoint Audio Devices 
Dual concurrent SCO connections
Multipoint Pairing

